# Padding and layout of card in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add padding to the text in the card and for some reason, it is not working.

This is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            height: 170.0,
            child: Card(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.phone),
                    title: Align(
                      child: Text('Need immediate help'),
                      alignment: Alignment(-1.2, 1.0),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Align(
                          child: Text('In an emergency, call 999.'),
                          alignment: Alignment(-1.2, 0),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          child: Text(
                              "If you're in crisis and need to speak to someone call NHS 111."),
                          alignment: Alignment(-1.2, 0),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  ButtonBar(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ButtonTheme(
                        minWidth: 150.0,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: const Text('999'),
                          onPressed: () => launch("tel://000"),
                        ),
                      ),
                      ButtonTheme(
                        minWidth: 150.0,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: const Text('111'),
                          onPressed: () => launch("tel://000"),
                        ),
```

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

I am wanting to add padding around the text so it looks better but using alignment isn't affecting the second subtitle and isn't affecting the padding above or below any of the text. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `mainAxisAlignment` property of your Column as following and remove the `mainAxisSize` property

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  // ...
),
```

**Edit**
Adjust your subtitle like this

```
ListTile(
  leading: Icon(Icons.phone),
  title: Align(
    child: Text('Need immediate help'),
    alignment: Alignment(-1.2, 1.0),
  ),
  subtitle: Align(
    alignment: Alignment(- 65.0, 1.0),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('In an emergency, call 999.', textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
        Text("If you're in crisis and need to speak to someone call NHS 111.", textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: That worked perfectly to move the text down, thank you! However, do you know why the second subtitle won't move inline with the other 2 lines of text by any chance?